# Seeking help understanding a step in an argument for counting ternary strings

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> *Problem*: How many ternary strings (using 0's, 1's and 2's) of length 8 either start with a 1, end with two 0's or have 4th and 5th positions 12?
>
> *Given solution*: Let $A_1$ denote the set of ternary strings of length 8 which start with a 1, $A_2$ denote the set of ternary strings of length 8 which end with two 0's, and $A_3$ denote the set of ternary strings of length 8 which have 4th and 5th positions 12. By the general rule of inclusion/exclusion our answer is $$3^7 + 3^6 + 3^6 − 3^5 − 3^5 − 3^4 + 3^3.$$

I can not understand the last part that why people are deducting and adding. Can someone please kindly help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

We wish to find $$\left| \cup_{i \in \{1,2,3\}} A_i \right|$$ In this particular case, Inclusion-Exclusion implies this is given by: $$|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|-|A_1 \cap A_2|-|A_1 \cap A_3|-|A_2 \cap A_3|+|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$$ which correspond to the numbers in the formula $$3^7 + 3^6 + 3^6 − 3^5 − 3^5 − 3^4 + 3^3$$ by individual counting arguments.  (E.g. $|A_1 \cap A_2|$ is the number of ternary strings of length 8 which start with a 1 and end in two 0's; so there's $3^5$ of them.)

(*Note*: Inclusion-Exclusion is Theorem 1 in the UND notes; this is the $n=3$ case.)

Comment: Could you please help me understanding this as well? Can someone help me explain a problem where suppose you have n antenna of which m are defective and n-m are functional and the functional antenna would be between two defective ones then the no of non negative integer would be n-m+2. So the no of possible ways that can be arranged would (n-m+1 C m) Similarly if there is two functional antenna between two defective ones then the no of non negative integer would be n-2m+3. This part is from Sheldon Ross book chapter 1. Please help me in explaining this?